# how to put flv file on a website without the player

Tags: flash

Is there a way to put up a flv file on the website? I don't want a player features, I just want to play it like it's an animation and then at the end just have a large play button to play it again. Are there any players that will allow me to do this?

Thank you

Comment: Are you willing to write any ActionScript program code, or are you just looking for a free player that can be customized?

Comment: I don't know any ActionScript but I guess I can figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [ActionScript's FLVPlayback component.](http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3flvplayback/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check out the JW Player. http://www.longtailvideo.com/players It may still have some controls, but you can usually customize it to look how you want it to.